# Unity3D and XCode 9 Beta - Hanging at compiling asset catalogs

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode9-beta

I'm building up a process for deploying to iOS 11 beta from Unity, using the latest XCode 9 Beta. I've followed the official guides, and everything goes fine until I get to compiling in XCode.

Whenever I start a compile it hangs forever at 'compiling asset catalogs'. This is despite using Unity's Simple Mobile Placeholder project, which has very few assets.

I've tried all the common solutions: from restarting XCode, to cleaning the build folder, all the way up to rebooting the computer.

Does anyone know of a fix, or at least a workaround for this issue? Unfortunately I cannot downgrade XCode because I need its new features for the project I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue myself.

While everything else was on the latest beta release, Unity was not. It seems that Unity3D's firm release does not build correctly for XCode 9.

The solution is therefore to update Unity to the latest beta release (2017.2.0b10 at time of writing).